# cant add more images to the script

Tags: javascript, html

how can i had mor images?

```
<script>
  var rotate = false;

  function setbackground() {
    newImage = rotate ? 
               'url(mimages/wallpaper2.jpg)' :
               'url(mimages/shutterstock_105126044-795x380.jpg)';
    rotate = !rotate;
    document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = newImage;
  }

  setInterval(setbackground, 4000);
</script>
```

i tried add the same way with :
did not worked

Comment: `did not worked` what does this mean? did you got any error?

Comment: What you want to do is not clear. Do you want to put different images in each interval? If yes, you must provide the list of images and in what order you want it to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could go about this. I'd recommend storing the url's of the images in an array, and incrementing a counter on each subsequent call of setBackground().

```
var images = [
    "url('mimages/wallpaper2.jpg')",
    "url('wallpaper2.jpg')",
    "url('wallpaper3.jpg')"
];

var imageIndex = 0;
function setbackground() {
             newImage = images[imageIndex];
             document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = newImage;
             if (imageIndex != images.length){
                 imageIndex++;
             }
             else{
                 // If we've reached the end of the array, reset the index
                 imageIndex = 0;
             }
             document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = newImage;
}

setInterval(setbackground, 4000);
```

When you want to add more images, simply add a new entry in the array.

Comment: Great spot, thanks Oz! I've now edited. Serves me right for not testing my code :).

Answer (score 0):

Your URL has to be enclosed inside a quote too

```
 newImage = rotate ? "url('mimages/wallpaper2.jpg')" : "url('mimages/shutterstock_105126044-795x380.jpg')";
```

Comment: it's not necessary

Answer (score 0):

You should create variable `newImage`.
Update your code to:

```
var rotate = false;

function setbackground() {
   var newImage = rotate ? 'url(mimages/wallpaper2.jpg)' : 'url(mimages/shutterstock_105126044-795x380.jpg)';
   rotate = !rotate;
   document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = newImage;
}

setInterval(setbackground, 4000);
```

See my demo [Here](http://codepen.io/huychau/pen/BzayLe?editors=1010)

Updated for more images:

```
var images = [
    "url(image.png)",
    "url(image2.png)",
    "url(image3.png)"
];

var index = 0;
var newImage = '';
function setbackground () {
  newImage = images[index];
  if (index !== images.length){
    index++;
  }
  else {
    index = 0;            
  }

  document.getElementById('change').style.backgroundImage = newImage;
}

setInterval(setbackground, 4000);
```

Comment: how can i had more images there is not problem with the code

Answer (score 0):

By passing more dynamic image name(path) to setbackground() function every call.

Comment: i did not got you what should i do?

Comment: @OzCohen, Please explain your requirement in details. I will send u full code.